# why isnt E a secure block cipher

Tags: pseudo-random-function, pseudo-random-permutation

Let $\pi : \{0,1\}^n \rightarrow \{0,1\}^n$ be a permutation.

Let $E(k, x) = \pi(x \oplus k)$ where $x,k \in \{0,1\}^n$.

Why isn't $E$ a secure block cipher?

---

My idea: Suppose $E$ is a secure block cipher.

If one let $k = 0^n$ and let $\pi(s) = s$ for any $s \in \{0,1\}^n$, then one can build an adversary that could guess, for example, that for $x_0 = 0^{n/2}1^{n/2}, \; x_1 = 1^{n/2}0^{n/2}$, the first half of $E(k, x_0)$ would be equal to the second half of $E(k, x_1)$ and the second half of $E(k, x_0)$ would be equal to the first half of $E(k, x_1)$. Such an adversary should have a considerable advantage and then $E$ couldn't be secure.

Comment: Hint: if the permutation $\pi$ is known to the adversary, how could he use that?  What if the adversary can compute $\pi^{-1}$?

Comment: @poncho if he knows $\pi(x)$, he could guess $k$ with only one query (if the query gives output $y$, then one just needs to search the value $v$ whose $\pi(v) = y$, and $v = x \oplus k$). Am I allowed to suppose that $\pi$ is known in order to prove insecurity?

Comment: @Daniel Since in your design $\pi$ is part of your *algorithm* and not your *key*, it is known to the adversary.